# how to solve the firebase install?

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

I'm so confused about the firebase when I installed. I can't figure out what happened in this situation. I hope anyone can do me a favor to solve the problem.

why the sign told me that it can't find my firebase storage. I written in the vi podfile.

[image]

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information. The podfile looks ok but it's unclear when and where the error is occurring. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your pod 'Firebase/storage', to 'Firebase/Storage' with a capital S. Then update your pod and see if that works.
Hope that helps! A thumbs up would be appreciated if this solves your problem